# Rails admin error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I'm building a rails app and now I would like to add the rails_admin gem I've added the gem to the gemfile and generated the initializers and configure it to use cancan and devise The app works as before I've added the gem I can see the main page of the admin console at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin/
```

I can manage all the other model but when i try to show and edit an instance of the model aircraft i get this error:

```
undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

full output: http://pastebin.com/Z2xDAmSc

after a little investigation I've discovered that the problem is the association between the aircraft model and the user through the pilot aircraft model:

this is my code:

aircraft.rb

```
class Aircraft < ActiveRecord::Base

 scope :without_other,         -> { where("name <> 'Other'").order('name ASC') }
 has_many  :pilot_aircrafts
 has_many  :authorised_pilots, -> { uniq }, through: :pilot_aircrafts, source: :user
```

pilot_aircraft.rb

```
class PilotAircraft < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :aircraft
 validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :aircraft_id
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :pilot_aircrafts
 has_many :authorised_aircrafts, -> { without_other }, through: :pilot_aircrafts, source: :aircraft
 has_many :all_authorised_aircrafts, through: :pilot_aircrafts, source: :aircraft
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :pilot_aircrafts, :allow_destroy => true,:reject_if => :all_blank
```

and the schema.rb

```
create_table "pilot_aircrafts", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.integer  "aircraft_id"
 ....
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I've spent all the afternoon experimenting but I couldn't find the problem,

other useful info:

ruby: 2.2.2
rails: 4.2.0
rails_admin: 0.7.0

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact error, with `klass`? Have you mistyped something somewhere, or is `klass` actually one of your models?

Comment: `klass` could actually indicate some error with AR wiring - Rails uses `klass` internally to avoid the keyword, like [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/activerecord/lib/active_record/translation.rb)

Comment: @undo I'm sure of it because is a direct ctrl+c ctrl+v from the error page I had the same reaction on the first time i saw the error but then I reached the conclusion proposed by max-alcala